# Simplificar subtração entre tabelas MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

Queria saber como simplificar o seguinte trecho:

```
SELECT FORMAT((SUM(r.valor_receita) - (SELECT SUM(d.valor_despesa)
FROM despesas AS d WHERE d.pago = 1 AND YEAR(r.data_vencimento) <= YEAR(d.data_vencimento)
AND MONTH(r.data_vencimento) <= MONTH(d.data_vencimento) AND r.id_usuario = d.id_usuario)),2,'de_DE')
AS saldo_efetivo
FROM receitas AS r WHERE r.recebido = 1 AND YEAR(r.data_vencimento) <= '2017' AND MONTH(r.data_vencimento) <= '06' AND r.id_usuario = 1
```

O que ele faz atualmente é somar o valor de todas as receitas recebidas (recebido = 1) e subtrair com o subselect que soma todas as despesas pagas (pago = 1).
Queria saber se dá pra simplificar esse query.

Comment: Alguém pra me ajudar aqui?

Answer (score 0):

Da maneira que está montada a estrutura de tabelas acredito que não há maneira melhor para fazer, porém se as estruturas de tabelas forem iguais, aconselho você a deixar tudo na mesma tabela com um campo que defina o tipo ("Despesa" ou "Receita"), por exemplo:

```
SELECT
    SUM(IF(tipo = 1,valor,valor*-1)) -- 1 - Receita / 2 - Despesa, Sendo assim faria o valor *-1 para ficar negativo
FROM tabela_contas
WHERE confirmado = 1 -- Seria se o valor foi pago ou recebido
-- E aqui o resto das suas condições
```